# Shrinking of union or intersection symbol for the intervals

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, amssymb

We use this very short MWE as an example. It surprises me that when constructing intervals with union or intersection symbols, `LaTeX` does not provide a minimum of space between a square bracket and these symbols. Visibly it all looks compressed.
[image]

> What is the reason and what could be a solution without inserted spaces (or to use the spaces)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document} 
$]-\infty,-1[\cup]-1,1[\cup]1,+\infty[$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell TeX you are using inverted brackets for intervals

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document} 
$\mathopen]-\infty,-1\mathclose[
\cup
\mathopen]-1,1\mathclose[
\cup
\mathopen]1,+\infty\mathclose[$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very kind of you David, with great sincerity I did not know this solution because I have never been interested in the question of brackets to be too close or too far from each other. Thank you very much....I wait 5 minutes for the green check mark :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano not only the spacing around cup you were getting binary  - not unary minus for the -1 in the middle